# Image transforms not working properly

Tags: image-transforms, image, json

I have 2 basic JSON files, the only difference between the files is the `product.type('')`

In my general.php I have turned on `'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,`

The first JSON file (200 products ) loads within 2 second and the image is like this:

```
http:\/\/mysite.dev\/files\/coins\/_transform\/1763-myImage.jpg
```

The second file (30 products) takes 10+ seconds to load, and displays the image like this:

```
http:\/\/mysite.dev\/cpresources\/404?x=CjvOQxsnA
```

I am using the same image transform for both files.
Why is it that the image in the second file isn't saved, because of this it takes 10+ seconds for the file to load.

I am using the same exact code for generating the transforms so I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you will see urls similar to this `http:\/\/mysite.dev\/cpresources\/404?x=CjvOQxsnA` if you have `generateTransformsBeforePageLoad` as `false`.

It could genuinely be the case that the original file is not there so it's 404ing (as the link suggests it is).
If you are running multi-environments, have you got all the assets on your locale env?

Maybe try clear your cache, or, your `storage/runtime` folder if you have all the assets and try again?

Comment: You are right, for some reason craft can't find the images even though the actual image is in my folder. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try find this particular file in the asset manager itself, then try "view" the file from there and see where it thinks it is located